# Nuxt 2 - the need to access 'this' when constructing computed ( for a zero import approach )

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i tried these:

of course the following will not work:

```js
    computed:{
       amount : this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount') // using Nuxt plugin but "this" is undefined here
    }
```

also `computed` as a function does not work:

```js
   computed(){
       return {
          amount : this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount')
       }
   }
/*
[Vue warn]: Invalid value for option "computed": expected an Object, but got Function.
*/
```

another way is importing something: ( which is ugly )

```js
import { syncStore } from '@/utils'  // importing in .vue is ugly
...
computed:{
    amount : syncStore('orders/amount') 
}
```

and i want a **zero import** approach . thanks to Nuxt plugins ,any helper code can be putted and accessed from `this`.

the only working code that i found [is this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/2d3379nh/), i copy a slightly modified code here:

```js
...
  beforeCreate() {
    if(!this.$options.computed)  this.$options.computed = {}

    this.$options.computed['amount'] = this.$myPlugins.syncStore('store1/amount')
  }
...
```

but it is a hack .

is there other ways ? thank you .

Comment: Would the second option (function) work if you make it a getter? `get computed(){  return ......`?

Comment: good idea , i tested it , i can access "this" , but nuxt plugins are undefined here :( , but nuxt plugins are available in beforeCreate . @trincot

Comment: i dont get it, computed elements is not a function?
`computed: { amount() { return this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount') } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 computed:{
       amount : this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount') // using Nuxt plugin but "this" is undefined here
    }
```

are you looking for this?

```js
computed: {
  amount () {
    return this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount')
  }
}
```

---- update use set and get in computed

this is in vue doc

```js
computed: {
  amount: {
    get () {
      return this.$myPlugin.syncStore('orders/amount')
    },
    set (val) {
      this.$myPlugin.methodToStore(val)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you , no i want to return `{ set(){}, get(){} }` object from the plugin. your way only returns a value . i want to use Vue computed setter getter.

Comment: it is possible to set setter and getter